# Programmatically Change Administrative Area in AddressField

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

I have some external data that I have introduced to Drupal for a users address (not in an address field). I am setting it so that when a user loads the checkout page in commerce their info is populated as the default field values.

How do I change the State (administrative area) to match the country that is set? Right now, if I have it set to Australia for instance, the State field is still set to United States relevant states.

Code Example:

```
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['first_name'] = $firstname;
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['last_name'] = $lastname;  
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['thoroughfare'] = $street;
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['locality'] = $city;
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['administrative_area'] = $state;
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['postal_code'] = $zipcode;
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['#address']['country'] = $country;
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_firstdata_billing_phone']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $phone;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, You need to use ajax. I think you will just need to alter the form structure a bit from what I have but the basic logic is there.

```
$country_list = array(0=>'USA',1=>'Canada');
$value_country = isset($form_state['values']['country']) ? $form_state['values']['country'] : key($country_list);

$form['country'] = array( 
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select Country'),
    '#options' =>  $country_list,  
    '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'name_replace',
        ),
 );

$form['state'] = array( 
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select State'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="name_replace"; style="margin-top:50px;">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' =>  mymodule_find_states($value_country), //pass country, run query, return correct states
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['country']) ? $form_state['values']['country'] : '',
 );
```

Add this function make sure this function is NOT inside form_alter function

```
function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['state'];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work. I am setting the country value from the start of the page load. I don't think there will be a change event.